# Keep fixed position element always visible when zoomed in on ipad

Tags: ios, css, iphone, ipad, viewport

I have a fixed position tab, similar to the feedback tabs you see on the right hand side of many websites. It is always on the right hand size of the page, on a desktop this is always in view.

The current CSS is:

```
cursor: pointer;
height: 120px;
margin-top: -60px;
position: fixed;
right: 0;
top: 50%;
width: 40px;
```

However, we want the tab to be visible when an ipad / iphone zooms and pans around a page, keeping the tab visible at the right side of the viewport, regardless of position and zoom. This way an ipad user can always see it and click it to open a panel.

Is there a way to do this with CSS using translate or similar?

My current solution involves adding events to gestures and touchstart / touchend, then positioning the tab by doing calculations based on zoomfactor, clientWidth, innerWidth and xOffset.

This doesn't behave that well currently and I'm looking for a simpler solution if possible. One that has good performance on iOS devices (I've seen a lot of examples that don't move well). I would like the tab to stay in view during all movements, rather than just repositioning on touchend.

Any tips or advice?

Thanks!